# While Loop SQL not populating complete results

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

**Question**: the iteration happens only till record 131 and gives accurate value, after that the parameter `@ADE_END_DATE` returns a `NULL` value, why would that be? Below is my code.

Additionally I noticed the column `Leave_Date` has `NULL` values and the iteration stops and returns NULL value for the parameter `@ADE_END_DATE` where the NULL value starts.

Thanks for your help.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HIREDATEPlus1Yr DATETIME
    DECLARE @ADE_Leave_Date DATETIME
    DECLARE @ADE_End_Date DATETIME
    DECLARE @ADE_Start_Date DATETIME
    DECLARE @DATECAL DATETIME
    DECLARE @i INT
    DECLARE @j INT
    DECLARE @Loop_length INT
    DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(18)

    -- start of loop
    SET @j = 1

    -- Loop length will equal to the list of all ADRs
    SET @Loop_Length = (SELECT COUNT([AD_ID]) 
                        FROM [DS_ADHOC_MOPs].[ADE].[List] 
                        WHERE Status NOT IN ('MANAGER', 'TBH', 'FROZEN'))

    -- Loop through each ADRs
    WHILE (@j <= @Loop_length)
    BEGIN
        -- Loop through each ADRs
        SET @i = 0

        -- Find AD ID
        SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 [AD_ID] FROM [DS_ADHOC_MOPs].[ADE].[List] 
                   WHERE [AD_ID] NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@j-1) [AD_ID] 
                                         FROM [DS_ADHOC_MOPs].[ADE].[List] 
                                         WHERE ([AD_ID] IS NOT NULL 
                                           AND Status NOT IN ('MANAGER', 'TBH', 'FROZEN')))) 

        -- Find the start date of the ADR
        SET @ADE_Start_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 [Hire_Date] 
                               FROM [DS_ADHOC_MOPs].[ADE].[List] 
                               WHERE [AD_ID] NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@j-1) [AD_ID] 
                                                     FROM [DS_ADHOC_MOPs].[ADE].[List] 
                                                     WHERE ([AD_ID] IS NOT NULL 
                                                       AND Status NOT IN ('MANAGER', 'TBH', 'FROZEN')))) 

        -- Hire date plus 1 year
        SET @HIREDATEPlus1Yr = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @ADE_Start_Date)

        --Adding Leave Date
        SET @ADE_Leave_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 [LEAVE_DATE] 
                               FROM [DS_ADHOC_MOPs].[ADE].[List] 
                               WHERE [AD_ID] NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@j-1) [AD_ID] 
                                                     FROM [DS_ADHOC_MOPs].[ADE].[List] 
                                                     WHERE ([AD_ID] IS NOT NULL 
                                                       AND Status NOT IN ('MANAGER', 'TBH', 'FROZEN'))))  

        
     -- Set a temporary variable which will be 1 year from now. Use the Date ADD formulae to start date, if they are leaver before one year then add leave date (Use IF): DONE
     -- Put everything inside the while loop and add opportunity selecting to it. 

    IF  @ADE_Leave_Date IS NULL 
        SET @ADE_End_Date = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @ADE_Start_Date)
    ELSE IF @HIREDATEPlus1Yr < @ADE_Leave_Date
        SET @ADE_End_Date = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @ADE_Start_Date)
    ELSE  
        SET @ADE_End_Date = @ADE_Leave_Date
    
    SET @DATECAL = datediff(DAY, @ADE_Start_Date, @ADE_End_Date)
     
    SET @j = @j + 1

    UPDATE #TEMPTABLEEEE 
    SET [@ADE_End_Date] = @ADE_End_Date
    WHERE @ID = AD_ID
END

SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLEEEE
END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It is from SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using a WHILE loop. It looks like this code could be much simplified. SQL is a set based language. Whenever possible, you should try to handle your data as a whole set instead of breaking it down into row by row evaluations.

Does this give you what you need? If the table has more than one row for each AD_ID, you will need to get the MAX() or MIN() Hire_Date/LEAVE_DATE. To improve the answer, consider providing sample data.

```
UPDATE t
SET     [@ADE_End_Date] = ed.ADE_EndDate
FROM    #TEMPTABLEEEE AS t
        INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT  AD_ID
                                ,CASE
                                    WHEN LEAVE_DATE IS NULL THEN DATEADD(YEAR,1,Hire_Date)
                                    WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,1,Hire_Date) < LEAVE_DATE THEN  DATEADD(YEAR,1,Hire_Date)
                                    ELSE LEAVE_DATE
                                END AS ADE_EndDate
                        FROM    DS_ADHOC_MOPs.ADE.List
                        WHERE   Status NOT IN ('MANAGER', 'TBH', 'FROZEN')
                    ) AS ed ON t.AD_ID = ed.AD_ID
```